# optimising 'du' reports on petabyte dataset?

Tags: linux, du

I am trying to get a daily filesize report on a dataset of several Petabytes of genomics data.
Our current report uses multiple overlapping `du` invocations to achieve the result, but takes over 24 hours to execute. I am looking for a way to do this more efficiently/quickly/'cleanly'.

currently we do:

```
# broad overview of dozens of projects + grand total
du -chd1 /petastorage/projects/  

# detailed look at some 'special' projects, 
# each of these has huge sub-dirs we want to track individually
du -hd1 /petastorage/projects/special_project_A/
du -hd1 /petastorage/projects/special_project_B/
du -hd1 /petastorage/projects/special_project_C/
```

What bothers me is that `special_project_[ABC]` are crawled twice, once in the grand-total overview, once for the detailed look. Since these special projects account for a big chunk of the data, crawling them twice is *probably* (warning: assumption) a significant part of the runtime.
Also, since we're talking about petabytes, I don't believe any level of filesystem-caching will accelerate the repeat invocations.

I've tried 'optimising' to
`du -d1 /petastorage/projects/  /petastorage/projects/special_project_[ABC]/`
but it seems `du` is smart enough to realise the special-projects are child directories of the first directory, and thus it 'optimises' them out of the reporting. Gah!

Does anyone have an idea how I can convince `du` to crawl my petabytes only once, outputting both all projects individually as well as the (one-level-deeper) detail-view of the three 'special-projects'

note: the current du-output is already put through some sort/uniq piping to make it display nicer and without duplicates in the email report, so solutions involving post-processing are acceptable. Any post-processing runtime is zero compared to `stat`ting petabytes of spinning rust.

Background in case it matters: this is an NFSv3 mount to EMC-isilon storage nodes, mounted on OpenSuse 11.4.
All projects currently share a single storage pool on the isilons so free space can be shifted between projects. Moving the 'special' projects to their own filesystems so we can 'cheat' with `df` is infeasible due to their size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To report back, we have since gone the "infeasable" route as part of a larger re-architecting of our storage.

Our new fileservers support quota per sub-mount, so over time we have been extracting projects into sub-mounts, instead of "normal" folders in a big, shared filesystem/mount. This was a back-burner migration project over multiple weeks/months.
This has allowed us to put quota on all the desired "folders".

We now query the quota status (which is managed live and instantaneously by the fileservers)

Comment: You could also assign different group IDs to projects, and query quota per group, then you don't need separate file systems.

Comment: Sounds interesting! Any docu you can point me at?
The IT-guys that did the quota-ing never mentioned support for group-level quotas.
Regardless: each project has its own (POSIX) access-group already, so the results would be identical to sub-mount quotas, with lots more finicky accounting for the server.
(Posix-groups because we have bad experiences with ACLs not being supported, or worse, being _only partially_ supported, so POSIX-groups are our only reliable tool for somewhat-scalable access management)

Answer (score 1):

After spending a (combined) day or two on this issue, we decided to go the easy way, and not optimise any further for now.
In the end, developer time is more costly than script-running time.

If/When I come back to this issue, I'll probably do one `du` run for the sub-projects, a second `du` run for the large folders (with an `--exclude` on projects covered by the first), and manually calculate the grand total together in post-processing (judidicious use of `awk`, `sed`, or `grep | paste -sd'+' | bc` should suffice)

If anyone else has better ideas, I'd be happy to hear them :-)

Comment: `du -hd2` should give you detailed views for all subprojects (which you can still throw away if you're not interested) as well as summaries.

Comment: Thanks @SimonRichter for the feedback!
It's been a couple of years since I worked on this, and `-d2`+filter was one of the things I evaluated; It ended up being more work to keep updating the filter-lists than it was worth, given the frequency with which projects were added/removed at the sub-levels.
Gave you an upvote because that is definitely something I should have listed in the answer!